# HOW-TO push/pull to/from Airflow X_COM with spark_task and pythonOperator?

Tags: python-3.x, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

I have a dag that creates a spark-task and executes a certain script located in a particular directory. There are two tasks like this. Both of these tasks need to receive the same ID generated in the DAG file before these tasks are executed. If I simply store and pass a value solely via the python script, the IDs are different, which is normal. So I am trying to push the value to XCOM with a PythonOperator and task.

I need to pull the values from XCOM and update a 'params' dictionary with that information in order to be able to pass it to my spark task.

Could you please help me, i am hitting my head in the wall and just can't figure it out.

***I tried the following:***

- create a function just to retrieve the data from xcom and the return it. Assigned this function to the params variable, but doesn't work. **I cannot return from a python function inside the DAG which uses the xcom_pull function**
- tried assigning an empty list and appending to it from the python function. and then the final list to provide directly to my spark task. Doesn't work either. Please help!

Thanks a lot in advance for any help related to this. I will need this value the same for this and multiple other spark tasks that may come into the same DAG file.

**DAG FILE**

```
import..
from common.base_tasks import spark_task

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1)
)

log_level = "info"

id_info = {
        "id": str(uuid.uuid1()),
        "start_time": str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f'))
    }

# this stores the value to XCOM successfully
def store_id(**kwargs):
    kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key='id_info', value=id_info)

store_trace_task = PythonOperator(task_id='store_id', provide_context=True, python_callable=store_id, dag=dag)           

extra_config = {'log_level': log_level}

config = '''{"config":"data"}'''
params = {'config': config,'extra_config': json.dumps(extra_config}

# ---------- this doesn't work ----------
pars = []
pars.append(params)

def task1_pull_params(**kwargs):
    tracing = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='store_trace_task')
    pars.append(tracing)
    # params = {
    #     'parsed_config': parsed_config,
    #     'extra_config': json.dumps(extra_config),
    #     'trace_data': tracing
    # }
    # return params     # return pushes to xcom, xcom_push does the same

task1_pull_params = PythonOperator(task_id='task1_pull_params', provide_context=True, python_callable=task1_pull_params, dag=dag)

store_trace_task >> task1_pull_params

# returning value from the function and calling it to assign res to the params variable below also doesn't work
# params = task1_pull_params

# this prints only what's outside of the function, i.e. params
print("===== pars =====> ", pars)

pipeline_task1 = spark_task(
    name='task1',
    script='app.py',
    params=params,
    dag=dag
    )

task1_pull_params >> pipeline_task1
```

Comment: have you tried pulling the xcom value inside your spark_task?

Comment: @RyanTheCoder no, you mean inside the python script I run in the task? Because I don't see where else I can try this, but not sure the xcom will be available from within the spark script itself. Will give it a shot though.

Comment: yeah, give it a shot. XCom values should be available in the downstream once you set them.